# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table' exception

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm trying to create login screen. When I enter the username and password, I receive an exception on the line:

```
sda.Fill(dt);
```

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'

My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    this.Hide();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Documents\admindb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;");

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count (*) From Table where username ='" + textBox1.Text +"' and password='" + textBox2.Text +"'",con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt) ;
    if(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
    {

    maincs ss = new maincs();
    ss.Show();
    }
    else
    {
    MessageBox.Show("Nichtig Username oder Password") ;

    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like C#, certainly it is not C - you should retag your question.

Comment: Having looked at your error it's an SQL syntax error. You need to replace "Table" with the actual name of the database table, for example "Users"

Comment: Furthermore, please do some research on SQL injection, and how to parameterise your queries

Comment: Try logging in with this username: `' OR '1'='1' -- ` and this one too: `'; DROP TABLE [Table]; -- `

Answer (score 1):

On the off chance that your table is actually called `Table`, you will have to enclose the table name in brackets:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = 
  new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count (*) From [Table] where username ='" +
      textBox1.Text +"' and password='" + textBox2.Text +"'",con);
```

Otherwise, as a commenter noted, you need to replace `Table` with the actual table name in your Sql.

Note: The exception you received should have pointed you right to the problem.

Comment: thnaks for replaying Sir ,, i tried but it does not works ,,, please see the photo below http://postimg.org/image/7upzid0pn/ ,,,,,,http://postimg.org/image/h7gu6e8mb/  ,,,,,,,, http://postimg.org/image/yzeeroykj/